# Authenticating to Azure AD as current user with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have an Azure App Service running Linux configured with Azure AD authentication per this [Microsoft document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)

Everything works fine if I access the site via a browser, as it handles all the necessary bits to authenticate as the user.  I'm not sure how to go about authenticating as the current user (which is an AAD account) logged into Windows via Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell though.  I'm assuming I need to retrieve some kind of token to pass along with Invoke-WebRequest.